# Overloading an operator that must return a reference to an object

Tags: c++, reference, overloading

```
class LongInt
{
public: LongInt& operator++(); //returning a reference
}

LongInt LongInt::operator++()
{
    ...

    LongInt d;


    d.setVector(temp);






    return d; //returning a reference to an object that will be wiped out because it is out of scope

}
```

I am kinda confused here. I apparently have to return by reference to overload the increment operator, but I don't think that's even possible. I get a memory fault, because the object my pointer is pointing to disappears. So how should I overload the ++ operator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify the object itself, then return `*this`.

Comment: if we modify the object, why do we have to return the reference to the object?

Comment: @user2967016 So that `++object` has the incremented value.

Comment: ... yeah, but if I modify the variable directly, I don't really have to return it, do I?

Comment: @user2967016 You do if you want expressions like `x = ++y` to compile.